# What is wrong with my run code using Inno-setup?

Tags: installation, runtime, ms-access-2007, inno-setup

I have written code with Inno-Setup to install a 2007 desktop MSAccess split data base and am including Access Runtime 2007. I have tried several variations of "running" the "AccessRuntime.exe" with the database but still get errors. Here are some of the constants and sections:

```
MyAppName "SSDExpress"
DefaultDirName=C:\{#MyAppName}
OutputDir= C:\{#MyAppName}
MyAppExeName "setup.exe"


[Files]
Source: C:pathtofiles\SSDExpress.accde; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: C:pathtofiles\SSDExpress_be.accdb; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: C:pathtofiles\AccessRuntime.exe; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

I have tried each of these 3 Run codes separately without success. Eachtime I have received errors related to the runtime.

1st try

```
[Run]
Filename:{app}\AccessRuntime.exe; Description:{cm:LaunchProgram,{#MyAppName}};Flags:
shellexec postinstall skipifsilent; Parameters: “””{app}\{#MyAppExeName}””/runtime”
```

2nd try

```
[Run]
Filename: Filename:{app}\{#MyAppExeName;Parameters: “/i””{app}\AccessRuntime.exe””/qn”
```

3rd try

```
[Run]
Filename: AccessRuntime.exe; Parameters: “/i””{app}\AccessRuntime.exe””/passive”
```

What am I doing wrong? (The code works to get all the files into the DefaultDirectory, but still I get messages that it cannot find the "AccessRuntime.exe" for the run code.)

Excuse my confusion in stating my problem. It may help to know that I have never written an installation script before. My only experience is using MS Access Packaging Wizard and I guess I assumed Inno was going to setup similarly.

To clarify what I want to do:  I am trying to get a script to create a setup for users, which I can send to them and they can run to install a desktop MS Access 2007 database (SSDExpress), which will require Access Runtime to run if they don't already have access. Ideally I would like to include Access Runtime in the install package for them vs a download. So I want the Setup to install the program, which when they then access it, it will run as a stand alone desk top program. I want the FE to be separate (vs. PW accdr file) so that I can update program changes as needed. 
I thank you in advance for your patience. Tricia

Answer (score 2):

The "1st try" is correct, and the others incorrect.  (Or at least the syntax is correct; you will have to discover for yourself what the correct parameters to pass to the runtime are.)

However two things to note:

1. This may have just been a side effect of posting it here, but your code includes "smart" quotes instead of standard quotes.  You will have to change these to standard quotes for it to work.
2. You do not have a space between the filename and the `/runtime` parameter in the `Parameters` value.

The very first thing that you need to do is to try running it yourself from the command line with the parameters you think you need, and make sure that this works.  Once you know that it works from the command line, it's just a simple matter of using the right syntax to get Inno to run it during the install.